Using CombiTable1Ds to define temperature dependant material properties
I created a material library where each material is a CombiTable1Ds with a different "table" variable (type Real).
The first column is temperature and the following columns are different properties for ex: y[1] is thermal conductivity and y[2] is density
when I try to set this parameters into variables in my model I am getting a "Translation Warning" that the units of the variable and the table are not the same and it shows me that the table is using the units of the first variable I set in the equation.
for example if my equation is
`k=materialTable.y[1]
rho=materialTable.y[2]`
I am getting:
`
The units of following sub-expressions need to be equal:

sub-expression "materialTable[2]" has unit "W/(m.K)"

sub-expression "rho" has unit "kg/m3"


`
If the table is real why does it have units and why does it get the units of the first parameter I am setting in the equation?

How to deduce units for variables in Modelica is not yet standardized. Having different units for different array elements is one of the issues that remain.
I don't know if the following works in OpenModelica, but it should be worth a try.
The first idea is to explicitly give a modifier for the unit for the elements of y - the y(unit={"W/(m.K)","kg/m3"}):
model Unnamed

  Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable1Ds materialTable(y(unit={"W/(m.K)","kg/m3"}), table=[0,1,2; 1,2,4])
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-20,-40},{0,-20}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.ContinuousClock continuousClock
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-100,22},{-80,42}})));
  Modelica.Units.SI.ThermalConductivity k=materialTable.y[1];
  Modelica.Units.SI.Density rho=materialTable.y[2];
equation 
  connect(materialTable.u, continuousClock.y) annotation (Line(points={{-22,-30},
          {-74,-30},{-74,32},{-79,32}}, color={0,0,127}));
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end Unnamed;

If that fails the following might work - but it is less convenient and teaches a trick that is very error prone:
model Unnamed

  Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable1Ds materialTable(table=[0,1,2; 1,2,4])
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-20,-40},{0,-20}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.ContinuousClock continuousClock
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-100,22},{-80,42}})));
    constant Modelica.Units.SI.ThermalConductivity unitThermalConductivity=1;
    constant Modelica.Units.SI.Density unitDensity=1;
    Modelica.Units.SI.ThermalConductivity k=materialTable.y[1]*unitThermalConductivity;
    Modelica.Units.SI.Density rho=materialTable.y[2]*unitDensity;
equation 
  connect(materialTable.u, continuousClock.y) annotation (Line(points={{-22,-30},
          {-74,-30},{-74,32},{-79,32}}, color={0,0,127}));
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end Unnamed;


both still show the same error

I have a workaround solution similar to what Hans suggested,
you create a variable for unit conversion:
real densityConvert(unit="(Kg/m3)/(W/(m.K))") = 1

and when you set density you multiply by the unit conversion variable
it is not a general solution, your conversion needs to be according to the first unit type used in equation with the table because it seems the entire table assumes this unit from there on.
